# How do I find the range of vales of $K$ satisfying the inequality $ k^2 - 9k + 16$?

Tags: inequality

the range of vales of K satisfying the inequality $k^2 - 9k + 16>0$    im quite confused, could you also explain how?

Comment: HINT: Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: And draw a graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k%5E2-9k%2B16%3E0

Answer (score 1):

So, Parth's solution is hinting at the answer to your question. The graph of the function $f(k) = k^2 - 9k + 16$ can suggest the solution to your inequality.

[image: Graph of $f(k) = k^2 - 9k + 16$]

Imagine selecting a point on the parabola. Each point represents a specific value of $k$ and the resultant value of $f(k)$ i.e. what you get when you substitute the value of $k$ into the expression $k^2 - 9k + 16$. So, if you are used to $(x, y)$ representing the value of a point on a graph, on this graph think of any point as representing $(k, f(k))$. For example, take $k= 3$. $f(3) = (3)^2 - 9(3) + 16 = 9 - 27 + 16 = -2$ on the graph the point $(3, -2)$ shows this value. Your questions asks how to find the range of values of $k$ for which $k^2 - 9k + 16 > 0$.

The range of values of $k$ for $f(k)$ is above the k-axis would be the range of values of $k$ that satisfy $k^2 - 9k + 16$. We can clearly see that the range is $(-\infty, 2.\text{something}) \cup (6. \text{something} ,\infty)$.

If you need to know the exact range you'll have to be able to identify the points where $f(k) = 0$. To do this solve the quadratic $k^2 - 9k + 16 = 0$

$k^2 - 9k + 16 = 0$

$a = 1, b = -9, c = 16$

$k = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$

$k = \dfrac{9 \pm \sqrt{(-9)^2 - 4(1)(16)}}{2(1)}$

$= \dfrac{9\pm \sqrt{81 - 64}}{2} \approx 2.438, 6.562$

Now we know that the range of values of $k$ is the union of two ranges. First the range between $-\infty$ (negative infinity) and $\dfrac{9 - \sqrt{17}}{2} \approx 2.438$ and second the range of $k$ from $\dfrac{9 + \sqrt{17}}{2} \approx 6.562$ up to $\infty$ (positive infinity). This can be expressed as

$\left(-\infty, \dfrac{9 - \sqrt{17}}{2}\right) \cup \left(\dfrac{9 + \sqrt{17}}{2}, \infty\right)$

Or in approximate decimal form as:

$\left(-\infty, 2.438\right) \cup \left(6.562, \infty\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Use the quadratic formula:

$\frac{-(-9) \pm \sqrt{(-9)^2 - 4(1)(16)}}{2(1)} = \frac{9 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}$

Take a value $k$ smaller or greater than one root. If $f(k)$ is smaller than $0$, then it is not in the range. This also works for smaller (or greater) values. (Why?)

Answer (score 0):

$ k^2 - 9k + 16  $ is a downward drawn parabola that cuts the $x$ axis at two points. Find them. Between those two points, the value of the expression is negative. So, for when K lies between those roots, your expression is negative.[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the quadratic formula you can see that $k^2 - 9k + 16$ has two real roots, $$\frac{9-\sqrt{17}}{2},\frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2}$$
so we can factor the polynomial to make your inequality into
$$\left(k-\frac{9-\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)\left(k-\frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)>0.$$
For this inequality to hold one of the following two conditions must be met
$$k-\frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2}<0,\  k-\frac{9-\sqrt{17}}{2}<0$$
$$k-\frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2}>0,\ k-\frac{9-\sqrt{17}}{2}>0$$
since if both are negative (the first condition) the product will be positive, and if both are positive (the second condition) the product will be positive. The first condition can be reduced to the statement
$$k<\frac{9-\sqrt{17}}{2}$$
and the second can be reduced to 
$$k>\frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2}$$
so these are the conditions for the inequality to hold.